# Database volume completely full

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, disk-space

/dev/mapper/pgdatavg-base
                         138304552 131262788     16384 100% /var/lib/pgsql/data/base

pg_xlog is on a separate volume, and it's got plenty of space.

```
[postgres@fpslbxmbstgl05 ~]$ psql TAP553 -c "drop index idx_log_attr_source;"
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "base/16384/pg_internal.init.32736": No space left on device
DETAIL:  Continuing anyway, but there's something wrong.
DROP INDEX
```

A `drop table` throws a similar error.

What can I do besides restore from backup?

Thanks

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.  Do you also get an error?

Comment: @jjanes disk space certainly was't freed.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do here is find the relfilenode of 'idx_log_attr_source', then shutdown the database and move the corresponding files (located in one of the base/* directories) somewhere else.  Then when you start up the database you should be able to drop the index.  If that succeeds, you could then get rid of the files you moved.  Symlinking might work, but I think it is riskier than not doing it.

```
select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='idx_log_attr_source';
```